# Want to use assets field my template settings in custom plugin craftcms

Tags: craft3, plugin-development, templating, assets

I am creating a plugin that is based on images the admin will upload some sort of images in plugin settings not sure how to creat image field setting in plugin

Answer (score 2):

To have asset selection and upload in your twig, you can use [elementSelectField](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/templates/_includes/forms/elementSelect.html)

the code i wrote here is just sample and definitely you need to review, consider security and validation

firstly you should have an extra public attribute to keep selected asset on settings model:

```
class Settings extends Model
{
    .....
    public $imageId = [];
    .....
```

in your settings.twig template you use elementSelectField like:

```
{{ forms.elementSelectField({
    label: "image",
    id: "imageId",
    name: "imageId",
    viewMode: "list",
    elementType: 'craft\\elements\\Asset', //limit to to asset element type
    selectionLabel: "Add Images",
    sources: ['folder:'~folderUid], //if you want to limit it to one volume folder not all volumes
    required: false,
    errors: settings.getErrors('imageId'),
    limit: 2, // if you want maximum two images 
    elements: images,  // at first it is null, then we pass selected assets as images 
    criteria: { kind: 'image'} // because you want only images
}) }}
```

in settingsHtml() method:

```
use craft\records\VolumeFolder;
protected function settingsHtml()
{
    $settings = $this->getSettings();
    // to load currently selected assets 
    $images = [];
    if ($settings->imageId) {
        foreach ($settings->imageId as $imgId) {
            $images[] = Craft::$app->elements->getElementById($imgId);
        }
    }
    //to limit asset selection to one folder
    $volume = Craft::$app->volumes->getVolumeByHandle('volumeHandle');//it could be the volume handle you created before
    $volFolderRecord = VolumeFolder::findOne([
        'volumeId' => $volume->id
    ]);
    $folderUid = $volFolderRecord->uid;
    return \Craft::$app->getView()->renderTemplate(
        'plugin-handle/settings',[ 
            'settings' => $settings,
            'images' => $images
            'folderUid' => $folderUid
     ]);
```

Comment: @DTS as i said in my answer this is only a sample. but have you copied exact code without any change? and which line of code has error?

Comment: @dts something is wrong with $setting. maybe you overwritted it. try to do craft::dd($settings) after $this->getSettings(); and also before $settings->imageId and see what it returns.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Happy to hear from you. I will definitely Look into it.

Comment: How to save the selected assets values in this??

Comment: @DTS in this case, no need to do anything. Craft does it. you can get image ids in your controller from plugin setting with $imageids = \yournamespace\Plugin::getInstance()->getSettings()->imageId;